# Android screenorientation change for all activities

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I want to fix screen orientation on my android application to portrait. Using google, i've found, that this can be done by adding the following code to my manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".LauncherActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

That's fine enough, but the problem is follows: I've about 15 activities now, and this number will grow. Is there any way to apply orientation to all activities at once?

I tried to use styles in a following way:

theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="Custom" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launcher</item>
    <item name="android:configChanges">keyboardHidden|orientation</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application ... 
android:debuggable="true"
  android:theme="@style/Custom"
>
//...
</application>
```

or

```
<activity
... 
  android:theme="@style/Custom"
>
//...
</activity>
```

Both the examples apply `windowBackground` succesfully, but `screenOrientation` does't works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No way. I need to repeat

```
<activity android:name=".LauncherActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

in every `<activity>` tag in manifest.

Answer (score 15):

You can create a class which extends `Activity` :

```
public class PortraitActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

And I think that if your activities extends `PortraitActivity` instead of `Activity` it will do.

**EDIT : SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT or SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE**

Comment: setRequestedOrientation() doesn't helps me anyway. In this case activity first orientates landscape for a moment, after that onCreate() calls and activity comes back to portrait. The "moment of landscape" is visible for user, especially on slow devices

Comment: it's an effective way. +1 for this.